# How to run win_disk_facts module on list of servers and print the drive size of all the servers in a list

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to run win_disk_facts module against the list of servers and fetch the max drive size among those servers.

Could someone please help me here. I tried to use this module and unable to fetch the drive size for multiple hosts.

Comment: Hi swetha, welcome to SO. You appear to have left off the "what error is your attempt producing for you" part of your question. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer suite for your question

```
- hosts: win_server
  tasks:
    - name: disk size
      win_disk_facts:

    - set_fact:
        size: "{{ ansible_facts.disks[1].size }}"

    - set_fact:
        E_DRIVE_SIZE: "{{ groups['win_server'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['size']) | join(',') }}"
```